# Как сделать анимацию?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation, animate

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать анимацию блоку такую, как это видно при наведении на него. Например, через каждые три секунды, чтобы она повторялась дважды. Раз-два...пауза 3сек... раз-два...пауза 3сек... и т.д. Спасибо!

```css
#arrow,
#arrow_top {
 z-index: 10;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
}
#arrow {
 
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#arrow_top {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#arrow .arrow {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
}
#arrow:hover .arrow {
 top: 5px;
}
#arrow .arrow_down {
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 background: red;
}
#arrow .arrow_down:after {
 position: absolute;
 content:"";
 top: 0px;
 left: 17px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: transparent;
 border-right: 3px solid red;
 border-top: 3px solid red;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
 transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow"><div class="arrow arrow_down"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если совсем по простому, при помощи css анимации, как-то так:

```css
#arrow,
    #arrow_top {
     z-index: 10;
     position: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 64px;
     height: 64px;
    }
    #arrow {
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
      animation: arrow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes arrow {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    
    70% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    
    73% {
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    
    76% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    79% {
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    
    82% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
    #arrow_top {
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
    }
    #arrow .arrow {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
    }
    #arrow:hover .arrow {
     top: 5px;
    }
    #arrow .arrow_down {
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     background: red;
    }
    #arrow .arrow_down:after {
     position: absolute;
     content:"";
     top: 0px;
     left: 17px;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     background: transparent;
     border-right: 3px solid red;
     border-top: 3px solid red;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
     transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
```

```html
<div id="arrow"><div class="arrow arrow_down"></div></div>
```